# Python GIL/Race conditions

Tags: python, gil

I'm trying to understand the Python GIL. My understanding is that since Python is compiled down into Python bytecode, when I have two threads decrementing a variable at the same time, theoretically, a race condition could occur. I'm wondering if this is the case, because I have been running the following code:

```
from threading import Thread
BIG_NUMBER = 500000000
count = BIG_NUMBER

def dec(n):
    global count
    for _ in range(n):
        count -= 1
t1 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 2,))
t2 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 2,))
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
print(count) # I have been getting 0 multiple times
```

Since BIG_NUMBER is set to 500,000,000, I would assume that a race condition could occur at least once and count would be indeterminate. But I keep getting 0?

Comment: GIL would indeed prevent that as threads won't be running in parallel.

Comment: @MYousefi  Although some people can't wait for Python to “drop” the GIL, the GIL makes multi-threading programming as simple as it can get. The GIL will ensure that there are no race conditions as long as operations are atomic i.e., thread-safe. --> Why does Python provide locking mechanisms if it's subject to a GIL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873512/why-does-python-provide-locking-mechanisms-if-its-subject-to-a-gil

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, the GIL ensures that only one thread at a time is executing Python bytecode. So operations that take one bytecode cannot be interrupted.

Let's use the `dis` module to look at your function:

```
In [1]: import dis

In [2]: def dec(n):
   ...:     global count
   ...:     for _ in range(n):
   ...:         count -= 1
   ...:         

In [3]: dis.dis(dec)
  3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 GET_ITER
        >>    8 FOR_ITER                12 (to 22)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (_)

  4          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (count)
             14 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
             16 INPLACE_SUBTRACT
             18 STORE_GLOBAL             1 (count)
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            8
        >>   22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

From `LOAD_GLOBAL` at 12 to `STORE_GLOBAL` at 18 is four bytecode instructions. One complete loop iteration takes seven bytecode instructions.
So technically, it is not an atomic operation.

The question is how often would a thread be interrupted in these four instructions?
For that we have to consider thread scheduling.

From a talk by David Beazley ("Embracing the Global Interpreter Lock"), I recall that a thread that wants the GIL in Python 3 must wait for *at least* 5 ms.
How many loop iterations you can run on a machine will obviously vary a lot. This is what I get on my machine.

```
In [1]: BIG_NUMBER = 500000000
Out[1]: 500000000

In [2]: count = BIG_NUMBER
Out[2]: 500000000

In [3]: def dec(n):
   ...:     global count
   ...:     for _ in range(n):
   ...:         count -= 1
   ...:         

In [4]: %timeit dec(1000)
68.8 µs ± 1.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So on my machine 5 ms would decrease the counter by about 100.

But still, four out of seven instructions in the loop need to run to maintain consistency. So a race condition should technically be possible, *if the thread is stopped at a random instruction*.

Answer (score 0):

I am also thinking about this nowadays. I don't know whether if decremention is single byte-code instruction or not. But if it is not, it is certainly possible to arrive at a nonzero result. Though we don't know the possibility of it. Probably would happen more regularly with high number of threads.

Also, a useful answer about consistency in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23855229/15282482

Comment: Why would more threads increase the probability? I don't think this is the case, since the switching interval would determine the probability, and that is independent of the number of threads.

Comment: what if lets say I have 2 cores assigned to my script  via  `os.sched_setaffinity(0, {0,1})` but script uses 8 threads ? would that increase the probability ?

Comment: in any case won't P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)  > P(A) or P(B) ?

Comment: @pippo1980, `sched_setaffinity` does not assign 2 cores to Python, it restricts the Python process to run on that 2 cores only. It will still run on one core at the same time, so I don't think it will make any difference (other than that _any_ change to the code or system could potentially change the timing behavior, so _could_ lead to different results).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33145438)

Answer (score 0):

this is not an answer, but was difficult to me to understand the question , so I slighty modified the code here; what I ended up with trying to understand what

> print(count) # I have been getting 0 multiple times

means, in the OP question. Hope I got it right:

```
from threading import Thread

# BIG_NUMBER = 500000000

BIG_NUMBER = 5  #messo da me se no troppo lento

count = BIG_NUMBER

def dec(n):
    global count
    for _ in range(n):
        count -= 1


results =  []

for i in range(10):
    
    BIG_NUMBER *= i+1
    
    count = BIG_NUMBER
    print(BIG_NUMBER, count)
    
    t1 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 2,))
    t2 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 2,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    # print(count) # I have been getting 0 multiple times
    
    results.append(count)
    
print(results)
```

output:

```
5 5
10 10
30 30
120 120
600 600
3600 3600
25200 25200
201600 201600
1814400 1814400
18144000 18144000
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 46670, 557348, 6385685]
```

adding :

```
import sis

sys.setswitchinterval(0.5)
print(' sys.getswitchinterval() : ', sys.getswitchinterval())
```

at the beginnig of code, I got results more in the likenesss of:

output:

```
5 5
10 10
30 30
120 120
600 600
3600 3600
25200 25200
201600 201600
1814400 1814400
18144000 18144000
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2626417]
```

see  [sys.setswitchinterval(interval)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setswitchinterval)

> sys.setswitchinterval(interval)

> Set the interpreter’s thread switch interval (in seconds). This floating-point value determines the ideal duration of the “timeslices” allocated to concurrently running Python threads. Please note that the actual value can be higher, especially if long-running internal functions or methods are used. Also, which thread becomes scheduled at the end of the interval is the operating system’s decision. The interpreter doesn’t have its own scheduler.

> New in version 3.2.

got from [Can you race condition in Python while there is a GIL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23855229/9877065)

as explained in post below https://stackoverflow.com/a/74380851/9877065

**ADDENDUM**

following discussion about answer below : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74380851/9877065

I added 2 threads to the ones in the original script and seems like

result are conparable to the previous ones

```
##########################################################################################

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855138/can-you-race-condition-in-python-while-there-is-a-gil/23855229#23855229
import sys
 
print(' sys.getswitchinterval() : ', sys.getswitchinterval())



######################################################################################



sys.setswitchinterval(0.5)
print(' sys.getswitchinterval() : ', sys.getswitchinterval())

from threading import Thread

# BIG_NUMBER = 500000000

BIG_NUMBER = 5  #messo da me se no troppo lento

count = BIG_NUMBER

def dec(n):
    global count
    for _ in range(n):
        count -= 1


results =  []

for i in range(10):
    
    BIG_NUMBER *= i+1
    
    # print(BIG_NUMBER)
    count = BIG_NUMBER
    print(BIG_NUMBER, count)
    
     t1 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 4,))
    t2 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 4,))
    t3 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 4,))
    t4 = Thread(target=dec, args=(BIG_NUMBER // 4,))
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()
    t4.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()
    t4.join()
    # print(count) # I have been getting 0 multiple times
    
    results.append(count)
    
print(results)
```

typical output:

```
sys.getswitchinterval() :  0.005
 sys.getswitchinterval() :  0.005
5 5
10 10
30 30
120 120
600 600
3600 3600
25200 25200
201600 201600
1814400 1814400
18144000 18144000
[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40218, 1005081, 11183482]
```

and

```
 sys.getswitchinterval() :  0.005
 sys.getswitchinterval() :  0.5
5 5
10 10
30 30
120 120
600 600
3600 3600
25200 25200
201600 201600
1814400 1814400
18144000 18144000
[1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2628116]
```

any comment on this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Re "_this is not an answer_". I think you've proven that for large enough values of `BIG_NUMBER`, it will be very likely that `count != 0`, which was the question indeed. You might explain it a bit better, but I think this is a valid answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, I think a lot depends on the computing power. Funny though decreasing `switchinterval`  [default value for me is 0.005 --> `sys.getswitchinterval() :  0.005` , the 5ms in @RolandSmith answer]  I cannot increase the wrong results : i.e. != 0. Any hint on that ?

Comment: I tried to reproduce these results with your script, but at my machine the results are all 0 (except for the first one of course). What Python interpreter did you use? Maybe interesting to include PC details as well.

Comment: Think its python 3.10.4 on Debian 11  VMware VM hosted by Ubuntu 22,   the guest uses just 1 of the host core. Adjust the code using exponential range ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11443737/how-to-generate-exponentially-increasing-range-in-python

Comment: I did update the code a bit and let it run for about half an hour without any race conditions. I was using Python 3.10.2 on Windows 10 (multi-core processor). Not sure if the OS or the fact that you were using only 1 core made the difference...

Comment: Mmh, forgot that I am running script in IDEwith own kernels with python binaries in virtualenv

Comment: "_that I am running script in IDEwith own kernels_" That is interesting information to add to your answer. The GIL is specific to CPython, so if you're using a different interpreter, that might explain why you get different results.

Comment: checked, scripts works exactly same behaviour running from terminal (IDE probably uses machine python when specifying it on preferences tab).